# Memory state is 100 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, memory-leaks

I am getting this log on my console `I/PhenotypeProcessReaper( 4606): Memory state is: 100`. Can anyone please tell what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not leave a comment because of my low reputation
This link can help you

[Handle memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69440737)